# set type of any of javascript object property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, casting, typescript-typings

I have the following javascript object

```
 venue = {
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    venueimage_set: [
      {
        imageurl: '',
      },

    ]...
```

then later in my code I change the object:

```
 this.venue.venueimage_set[+image] = this.venue.venueimage_set[+image].imageurl;
```

for a image viewer to work I need the url of the image only not the key that the image url is part of. So I take whats in the key and set the array position to the keys value, the image url.

then I get this noise.

`ERROR in mainroot/venuepage/venuepage.component.ts(171,25): error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ imageurl: string; }'.
mainroot/venuepage/venuepage.component.ts(175,127): error TS2339: Property 'imageurl' does not exist on type 'string'.`

I would like typescript to ignore typing and just let me do this. How would I?

Comment: Why are you using typescript at all if you are doing some very weird type mixing? `for a image viewer to work` there will be probably a far more elegant way that also ensures typesafety.

Comment: @JonasW. because I want  my slideshow plug in to work, and I am using typescript because angular uses typescript, and I hate javascript. Even in Java I can manipulate and cast types as I see fit if I have to in werid uses cases like these

Comment: Just add `as any` following the expression.

Comment: @JonasW. there most likely are but I am not going to let my bussiness hold off while I make a more elegant solution to something so trival. Just want it to work and move on.

Comment: Writing unsafe code might work "now" but it might somehow stop working somewhen and then you are in troubles.

Comment: @JonasW. this is interesting I literrally add the words `as any` to the end of the expression? I tired it out and it seems to work.

Comment: @JonasW. and I won't be doing what you are suggesting in your answer only because this is a placeholder object. The object gets replaced with an object  from the database. its just to make my code not break while it is waiting for the http reponse on the inital of the component

Comment: Then just turn that response into a Venue when it arrives and assign that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a typesafe version of what you're trying to do:

```
function toVenue<T>({id, name, venueimage_set}: T) {
  return {
    id,
    name,
    venueImageSet: venueimage_set.map(el => el.imageurl)
  };
}
```

Which can be used when setting `venue`:

```
const venue = toVenue({
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    venueimage_set: [{
       imageurl: '',
    }]
});
```

---

And here the unsafe version (please don't do this):

```
this.venue.venueimage_set[+image] = this.venue.venueimage_set[+image].imageurl as any;
```

Comment: the as any was not accepted  in my code. this is werid